# File Organization in Rhythmbox: Disc Number in front of Track Number

Tags: 20.04, gnome, music, rhythmbox, organizer

I recently installed the **[File Organizer Plugin](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Plugins/ThirdParty#File_Organizer)** for [Rhythmbox](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rhythmbox) music player and organizer for GNOME.

Now when I try to setup the organization of my music under *Preferences > Music > Library Structure* I get the following settings for `File name` and `Folder hierarchy`

[image]

which is precisely what I would like except that if I have albums made up by more than one disc I would like the File Organizer to prepend the disc number to the name, like

```
../Help!/01-07 - Ticket To Ride.m4a
```

Weirdly I can insert the disc number to the music file metadata

[image]

But I can't set it as a parameter in Library Structure

[image]

I don't like the solution someone proposd to change the Album name so that it includes the disc number, since it is a meta information one should be able to use it as file name formatter.
If there is a workaround by editing python codes or some guides that could help me anything is welcome.
Thanks for your time.

#### More infos:

```
$ rhythmbox --version
rhythmbox 3.4.4
$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a "so-so" solution (meaning it is not completely satisfying). Using the [`dconf-editor`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DconfEditor) tool, inspired by [this discussion](https://answers.launchpad.net/rb-fileorganizer/+question/182442) I managed to find the `layout-filename` setting (under `/org/gnome/rhythmbox/library/layout-filename`) and changed from the default value

```
%tN - %tt
```

to

```
%aN-%tN - %tt
```

which gives somehow what I wanted, since the format specifier `%aN` stands for the

> %aN -- album disc number, zero padded

key, sadly this prepends to albums with no disc number the awful looking "00" disc number

#### Ok behavior

[image]

#### Non ok behavior

[image]

I think at this point the only needed feature is to conditionally prepend the `%aN` formatte only if the number is not `00`.

Comment: That would make for a valid issue request to the developpers. An alternative workaround - which actually makes sense in the digital world where there is no CD 1 and CD 2, would be to number your tracks incrementally for subsequent disk.

Comment: After renaming the files in your library using the File Organizer Plugin, you could perhaps run a script to remove `00-` from the files in your library that use it. You could use for example something like this with `find` and Perl `rename` from within your library: `find . -type f -name "00-*" -exec rename -n 's/00-//' {} \;` (`-n` is used to preview the changes; remove it to apply them).